# Cant save as xaml in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I was Trying to Save an SVG in XAML format to use it in my C#-WPF Project, but since today the "Microsoft xaml" option isn´t showing up in the "save as" window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K27O2.png)

How Can i get the Option back?

I already tried to reinstall Inkscape, without success. The Item is still missing in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Inkscape 1.3, and there is a work-around found in the Inkscape bug ticket:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/4502

> Jonathan Neuhauser
> @joneuhauser
> · 1 month ago · Developer
>
> It will be fixed for 1.3.1. In the meantime, you can download https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extras/extension-xaml and extract / clone it into the directory listed at Edit > Preferences > System: User extensions.